# Developing an iphone app to connect to SAP

Tags: xcode, netweaver, sap-mii

I have downloaded xcode and have developed a crud app (on the iphone) that interacts with a MySQL table using PHP on a Linux server.

Now I want to develop a crud program on an iphone that can connect to SAP.

I have xcode and access to SAP.  What more do I need to accomplish this?

Do I need to license software from SAP?  Or is there open source software that will allow me to do all this?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need the SAP Mobile Development Kit NetWeaver Mobile 7.0 but I would like an open source alternative.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download and install xcode.
Download and install the Gateway Consumption Tool from SDN. (You will need to be a registered dev with SAP to do this).
Make sure your gateway service on SAP is installed correctly.

You can now start developing.

For more info go here: [Consume a Gateway Service Using XCode](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20to...%20consume%20a%20gateway%20service%20using%20xcode&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/index?rid=/library/uuid/40530676-117e-2e10-979f-d7892e6a492d&overridelayout=true&ei=2z8VT5fBEYSGhQfxrqiEAg&usg=AFQjCNG4JgGGrYEhw_jiy1VZQz472f2BAg&sig2=hzoTGE8R_oIrguGKjqeOiw&cad=rja)